# LightDM theme is not acting normal

Tags: unity, login, themes, lightdm, display-manager

fellow Ubuntu Enthusiasts!  I recently installed LightDM via `sudo apt install lightdm` and then installed lightdm settings tool via `sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`
And now, LightDM looks all weird.  It doesn't have the look that it used to with a fresh lightDM install.  Can somebody please help me to restore all the settings?
My lightDM theme looks like this right now:
[image]
But I want it to look like this:
[image]
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, Focal Fossa, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightDM comes in different flavours. The first screen indicates that you have the lightdm-gtk-greeter activated.

You control those settings settings in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[LightDM]
run-directory=/run/lightdm

[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
user-session=xfce
session-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/Xsession
```

In addition to that are "slickgreeter" or "unity-greeter" which you may have to install before configuring them.

Ubuntu on the other hand uses the GDM (GnomeDisplayManager) which has a complete different look and feel.

So I'd go for the slickgreeter -I think Linux Mint uses that - to get a close look to your second screen

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  How would I install unity-greeter, or slickgreeter?  When I first installed lightdm, it looked exactly like the second picture.  I have also reinstalled it a few times, and have had no luck restoring it.  There is also no lightdm.conf file there.

Comment: I figured it out!  I had to create a new `lightdm.conf` file.  And had to construct it manually.  +1 thanks for your answer though!  It worked after I created my own config file.

Comment: Maybe distro dependent. Since ubuntu does not have lightdm by default that may be the reason. Glad you got if figured out